# Where does Unity 5.6 Render into the ShadowMask when lights aren't baked

Tags: rendering, unity-game-engine, shadow

I'm currently trying to use CommandBuffers to render lights and shadows for my geometry using CommandBuffer.DrawProcedural it work's but only when objects rendered overlap this new ShadowMask.

[Here is you can see the masking effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIqxN.png)

[And this is the Shadowmask Buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGv30.png)

So I guess my question is does unity have a way to render into that mask with a CommandBuffer or do I just throw a mesh cube around my game world?

Comment: I forgot to mention the tiny little man are the meshes draw procedurally where the green and grey boxes are traditional unity meshes.

Comment: It seems to be resulting from a stencil operation in the builtin deferred shader if I find an answer i'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this stencil mask to my deferred pass allowed lights to be rendered properly when using light and shadows with drawprocedural and commandbuffers

```
Stencil{
            ref[_StencilNonBackground]
            Comp Always
            Pass Replace

            ZFail Keep
            Fail Keep
        }
```